# npm going to user directory when running npm test script

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

I've just finished up writing a test suite and, after adding the test file to the npm scripts object in the local package.json, I appear to have warnings that the package.json cannot be found in the user directory.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\chris\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\chris\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-04T16_59_06_479Z-debug.log
```

Why is it going to the user directory instead of the current directory, which is `C:\Users\chris\Google Drive\code projects\firebase-form\firebase-form`? Is it a problem with the script test command, which is `"test": "mocha tests/firebase-listeners-tests.js"`?

Also, for additional information here is my projects file structure:

```
firebase-form/
├── tests/
│   ├── firebase-listeners-tests.js
│   ├── resources tests.js
│   └── test_dependancy-fake_data_for_firebase.js
└── package.json
```

As you can see I do not have an entry point .js file, but that's because I haven't finished testing yet.

Comment: you're not showing where, and how, you run your npm script. Are you just running `C:\Users\...\firebase-form> npm test`?

Comment: sorry, it's `C:\Users\chris\Google Drive\code projects\firebase-form>npm test` that I'm running

Comment: I assume you read through `2018-08-04T16_59_06_479Z-debug.log`, what did that tell you?

Comment: sorry stack exchange is not letting me post the whole error log , nor format it. give me one sec

Comment: [Here are the logged errors](https://i.imgur.com/I2h9ZIS.png)

Comment: This feels like a problem with the npm install, which you should probably ask about in the most authoritative place for NPM questions: https://npm.community/c/bugs